# Explode on last found PHP

Tags: php, explode

Let's say i have this string

```
One.Two_Three_Four.Five.Six_Three_Eight ...
```

How can I get all the strings before and after last "Three_"

I'm thinking of using explode.

Comment: explode will return an array with 4 items, unless the `.` between Three and Four is something only LOOKS like a `.` but isn't actually one.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a limit in `explode()`, but since you want it off the end, you can do a [`strrev()`](http://php.net/strrev) - so the last dot becomes the first.

```
$string = strrev($string); //reversed
$data = explode(".", $string, 2);
$data = array_map("strrev", $data); //strings in correct order
```

But since the string was reversed, `$data[0]` will now be `"four"` and `$data[1]` will be `"one.two.three"`

Comment: I just changed my question, please check :(

Comment: @user3749450 Can't you use `_Three_` instead of `.` for exploding?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the text after the final `.`, then use something like this:

```
$string = "One.Two.Three.Four";
$last = substr($string, strrpos($string, '.') + 1);
echo $last; // Four
```

**Edit**

OP changed his question to something completey different, but I'll leave this here anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_pop()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

```
$string = "A.B.C.D.E";
$a = explode(".",$string);
array_pop($a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution may be

```
$parts = explode(".", $string);
$last = array_pop($parts);
$other = implode(".", $parts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Explode returns a array so you have to iterate through it to view all the values. You can do that directly or using a foreach(for).

```
$string = "One.Two.Three.Four";

$a = explode(".",$string);

echo $a[0]; // One
echo $a[1]; // Two
echo $a[2]; // Three
echo $a[3]; // Four

// Or

foreach ($a as $v){
    echo $v; // One, Two, Three, Four
}
```

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php

If you want just the LAST element you can do something like this:

```
echo end($a); // Four
```

http://www.php.net/end

Comment: this is not helping at all. What if the string is longer?

Comment: @user3749450 use foreach, the first ones is for directly access

Comment: @user3749450 use array_pop() fuction

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$string="one.two.three.four";
$array = explode(".",$string);
$last= end($array);
echo $last;
```

This will do the trick if you want to allways have the last in the array. First you explode the string into an array and then you take the array and use `end`.